# How to set the subversion repository root in Debian?

Tags: debian, svn, root, repository

I have just switched from an old Fedora Core server to Debian Linux v5.0.4.

Having migrated the old repository and configured access through svn+ssh, I now want to be able to access the repository with the same path on the client as before.

On Fedora you could specify the repository root with "svnserve -r " but having checked the config files and svnadmin options I'm stuck as to how I can do this on Debian.

Is there a way to set the repository root in Debian?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth

(see "Controlling the invoked command").

You can specify the command to be invoked, including the repository base, in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys:

i.e.

> command="/usr/bin/svnserve -t -r " ssh-dss AAAA...

This approach means you won't be able to log in to the command prompt with this user.